# How to play VS Survival in Killing Floor 2 with group of friends on PS4?

Tags: killing-floor-2

We have 8 players who want to play the VS Survival mode in Killing Floor 2 on PS4 where half of us are zombies and the other half are humans.

How do we do this?

We tried to set it up last night with all of us in the same PS4 party - but it only showed 6 places in a "squad" and the remaining players couldn't join.

Do two players need to set up separate PS4 parties?

If anyone could give me instructions on how to setup a VS Survival game for a group of friends in Killing Floor 2 on the PS4 it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So getting an 8 man party is a lot simpler than I had thought also. Once you select online matchmaking and then set the game mode to VS Survival, you need to set the permissions to Invite Only if you only want to play with those 8 friends. You do not have to have everyone in your squad just yet. You can search for an online game that is set to Invite Only when you are the only one in the party. Once you have loaded into a map and before you have readied up, you should see this [image: screen] You can enter the squad screen here and invite everyone.

Comment: Cool, will give this a crack

Comment: On PS4 for me it was pressing the touch pad to create party and it brought up the invite menu

Comment: @n_palum yes, you have to hit the touchpad to enter the squad screen. But you need to be in the vs survival lobby in order to invite more than 5 other people.

Comment: Oh I know I was just adding on that bit since it wasn't mentioned

Comment: @BaronGrivet did this work for you?

Comment: @LostWookie - haven't had a chance to try it yet. Will let you know by the end of the week.